# error when i start job in hadoop

Tags: bash, ubuntu, hadoop

j just want to install hadoop single node mode in ubuntu i formatted hdfs succesfully but when i start the job with start-all.sh  I am getting error message as

```
 rochdi@127:~$ start-all.sh

/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 62: [: localhost: integer expression expected

starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-rochdi-namenode-127.0.0.1

localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 62: [: localhost: integer expression expected

localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-rochdi-datanode-127.0.0.1

localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 62: [: localhost: integer expression expected

localhost: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-rochdi-secondarynamenode-127.0.0.1

/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 62: [: localhost: integer expression expected

starting jobtracker, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-rochdi-jobtracker-127.0.0.1

localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 62: [: localhost: integer expression expected

localhost: starting tasktracker, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-rochdi-tasktracker-127.0.0.1

localhost: Erreur : impossible de trouver ou charger la classe principale localhost
```

and this is my bashrc config file

```
export HADOOP_PREFIX=/usr/local/hadoop

export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_PREFIX/bin

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
```

and when i use jps command:

```
> rochdi@127:~$ jps
3427 Jps
```

help me please

Comment: Can you please try aligning your commands and the output if each of them so that we understand exactly how many commands you have run and what did they return?

Comment: erreur: impossible to find or load main class localhost

Comment: What is the output of JPS?